# alignment of an image within a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jtextarea

I am currently trying to visualize a couple of images with two JTextAreas below. The following happens: The images are centered and the text within the JTextAreas is left aligned. I would like to be able to also display the images on the left.
I am using the following code to make the panel

```
public MetaboliteInfo(SwingEngine se)
    {
        super();
        Engine engine = se.getEngine();
        engine.addApplicationEventListener(this);
        VPathway vp = engine.getActiveVPathway();
        if(vp != null) vp.addSelectionListener(this);

        this.gdbManager = se.getGdbManager();
        this.se = se;

        setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
        add (scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);           

    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the text areas or the images.  How are you displaying them? Via labels?

Comment: Why not instead of using `BoxLayout`, you use `GridLayout` like `new GridLayout(0, 1)`, that way you can achieve what you intent to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Comment: @user992484 I am using `ImageIcons` within `JLabels` for the images and then add them to the panel via `panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)))`